# data hiding for python QTconsole

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, qtconsole

Currently I am making an image authentication project in which I need to authenticate an image with the help of a key. I am taking the key as a `raw_input` from the user through the IPython console. I want to hide the key being entered.

Expected Result:

`Enter the key = *****` or `Enter the key = (nothing shown)`

I found `getpass()` method for hiding the entered data but it gives the following warning on my PC:
`Warning: QtConsole does not support password mode, the text you type will be visible.`

I even saw this code:

```
import sys
import msvcrt

passwor = ''
while True:
    x = msvcrt.getch()
    if x == '\r':
        break
    sys.stdout.write('*')
    passwor +=x

print '\n'+passwor
```

But this prints infinite number of asterisks on the display.

Please let me know some solution for this problem.

Comment: `getpass` works out of Spyder. This is a limitation of Spyder/QtConsole, not of getpass itself.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba thanks. But do you know any function or code that could suffice my need?

Comment: Not that will run inside Spyder. You can go to `Run > Configuration per file > Console` and select the option called `Execute in an external terminal` to use an external terminal instead.

Comment: Please see a workaround in linked question, and if you can, please add the Windows-specific basic GUI commands in Option 1.