# Maskpass Case Insensitive and Special Characters Issue - Python

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, special-characters, case-sensitive

I am using maskpass in Spyder to hide a password input but am having issues with using the Shift key for uppercase letters and special characters.

My code for this section is as follows:

```py
import maskpass
pwd = maskpass.advpass()
```

During testing, I realized that the input is not reading uppercase letters or special characters (driven by using Shift). For example, "Abc123!" is being read in as "abc1231". I tried putting on Caps Lock to handle the uppercase letters, but that didn't work. Any ideas on why this is and how to fix it? Is maskpass not equipped to handle case sensitive passwords and special characters? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I also use Spyder as my IDE of choice and was very annoyed trying to find a solution. Maskpass looked like exactly what I needed since it advertises that it works with Spyder! ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47213310/getpass-is-not-working-for-spyder-python)):

> Warning: QtConsole does not support password mode, the text you type
> will be visible.

However, when I tried to use the `maskpass.advpass()` function, I also realized that it was not registering the case changes and special characters that most systems require when setting passwords (hence the reason I'm on this thread). However, it dawned on me that my users were not going to access my scripts from Spyder. I have a batch file that my users run so everything is in a command window. So I ran a test. I created a simple login function:

```
def sp_login():
     import maskpass
     user_name = input('User name>> ').upper()
     password = maskpass.advpass()
     return password

print(password)
```

Wouldn't you know it, when I ran the script from the batch file, it returned the correct letter case and special characters as I input them. I still used `maskpass.advpass()` instead of  `.askpass()` because you can still toggle the view using the left-side CONTROL key in the command window and I thought that would come in handy for users.

So yes, maskpass in Spyder is glitchy, but if your users aren't using Spyder to provide the password input, you should still be okay. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, libraries that hide passwords requested via `input` don't work in Spyder, sorry.

This is due to a limitation of the Jupyter architecture to run code, which we also use in Spyder. So there's nothing to do about it.

Answer (score -1):

There's another solution for Spyder.  Pick a character that's not in passwords, or at least most passwords, say '='.  Now imagine a keyboard input using numbers, letters, and the upper cases for each -- on the keyboard, that is, so that upper(4) = $.  Now use '=', which is passed through by advpass, to serve as a shift key.  So if the user's password is "CoolPassword$$", she would enter '=cool=password=4=4' (or '=Cool=Password=$=$').  The decoding is straightforward, the typing's not too bad (just remember '=' before each use of Shift-), and the invisibility of the password is retained.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).